# How to add the results of two mysql queries on a php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two queries on a PHP page:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT *, SUM(commission1) FROM agents WHERE b=1"; //GROUP BY commission1" 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total = ". $row['SUM(commission1)'] . "  ";
}
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT *, SUM(commission2) FROM agents WHERE b=2"; //GROUP BY commission2" 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Total = ". $row['SUM(commission2)'] . "  ";
}
?>
```

I would like to add the two results in a separate row.
I tried to find a solution, but I couldn't.

Comment: Store both results in a variable and add them. Or use an `UNION ALL` to combine both queries.

Comment: `SELECT *, SUM(commission2)` is invalid ANSI SQL. MySQL accepts and executes the query if the server isn't running in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode..

Comment: Extending @RaymondNijland's point, I really wouldn't use MySQL's non-full-group-by syntax, you will confuse the hell out of anyone maintaining your code in the future who's ever used any other RDBMS.